# Are there any good logo creation applications available for Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, vector-graphics

Are there any good logo creation applications available for Ubuntu?  Something other than Gimp.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't like Gimp, you can use [InkScape](http://www.inkscape.org/).
If you have a Windows program that you like, you might try to run it in Ubuntu using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/) ("Wine Is Not an Emulator").

Comment: see also CrossOver Office :)

Answer (score -4):

I believe that a new Photoshop and maybe other adobe products are now avalaible for linux. If you give it a try, please tell us if that worked.

Comment: CAn this be downloaded from Adobe's Website?

Comment: You believe wrong.

Comment: @Roland, trial versions can be downloaded I think. However, they are for Windows and OS X, as far as I know (http://www.adobe.com/downloads/)

Comment: Thanks Svish, I also thought there wasn't a linux version "I wish there was"

Comment: I believe one of the recent Photoshop versions (CS2 maybe) runs fine on Linux with WINE.